# Knockout: Mapping/binding JSON

Tags: json, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout. I'm trying to bind the json returned from ajax call but it isn't happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var ServerData;

 $(document).ready(function () { 
      ko.setTemplateEngine(new ko.nativeTemplateEngine); 
      var oViewModel = new CompanyModel();   
      oViewModel.Newitem(new Company("","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""));
      ko.applyBindings(oViewModel);
      BasicDatatable('#TableCompany'); 
 });

 function CompanyModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.CompanyList = ko.observable();
     $.getJSON("getallcompanies", function (response) {
         ServerData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(response);
         self.CompanyList(ServerData);
     });
 }
```

In `response` I've the required data. But in `ServerData` I'm getting the following instead of the list.

`function b() { if (0 < arguments.length) { if (!b.equalityComparer || !b.equalityComparer(d, arguments[0])) b.H(), d = arguments[0], b.G(); return this } r.T.Ha(b); return d }`

Can You please let me know what's going wrong?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `ko.mapping.fromJS(response)`

Comment: How are you querying/inspecting ServerData? You usually see that if you don't unwrap the observable (miss the brackets off): try `console.log(ServerData());` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ko.mapping.fromJS` to bind JSON that comes from server.

Also, you **don't** need to define `self.CompanyList = ko.observable();` and bind set value to that property in `self.CompanyList(ServerData);`.
It's all done by `ko.mapping.fromJS`. From Knockout Mapping documentation:

- All properties of an object are converted into an observable. If an
  update would change the value, it will update the observable.
- Arrays are converted into observable arrays. If an update would
  change the number of items, it will perform the appropriate
  add/remove actions. It will also try to keep the order the same as
  the original JavaScript array.

Try to change code like this:

```
 function CompanyModel() {
     var self = this;

     $.getJSON("getallcompanies", function (response) {
         ko.mapping.fromJSON(response, {}, self);
     });
 }
```